# How do I add proxies to a request to prevent limiting of an API

Tags: python, api, proxy, python-requests

Let's say I have these multiple proxies and I want to use them to request information from an API

```
proxies = open("proxies.txt", encoding="UTF-8", errors="ignore").read().splitlines()
proxies = list(proxies)

https_proxy = random.choice(proxies)
proxyDict = {"http" : "http://"+https_proxy}

req2 = c.get(url=url2,timeout=timeout, proxies = proxyDict).json()
example = req2['data']
```

This does not seem to work for me, I use this script and it seems like my IP is still being limited even though I request with a proxy, any help will be appreciated.